# minmax of hamming weight in a basis for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-algebra

Consider the vector space $V=\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ and take some linear subspace $U\subseteq V$ (we can assume we are given some basis for $U$). Now, for every basis $B$ of U, define $f(B)=\max_{b\in B}\{w(b)\}$ where $w(b)$ is the hamming weight of $b$ - the number of nonzero entries in it.

My goal is to compute $\min_Bf(B)$ where $B$ ranges over all the bases of $U$ (only a finite number of such bases exist since $V$ is a finite vector space).

I can use brute force, but prefer a better algorithm.

Comment: The question: *Does there exist a vector of weight $\le k$ in $U$*, belongs to one of those nasty problem classes in the NP-hierarchy, so I am not very hopeful. That is not exactly your question, but anyway suggests the possibility that an efficient algorithm may not exist.

Comment: But isn't this question solvable over $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ with Gauss-Jordan? If I recall correctly, in error-correcting codes the min weight of a code is found by Gauss-Jordan on the parity checking matrix.

Comment: There is no known efficient method for finding the minimum weight of a linear code. If one were found, it would revolutionize coding theory. Might also settle the $NP=P$ question, but I'm not sure about that.